# How to setup email verification for newsletter signup using webforms?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, email

I am creating a webform for newsletter signup. Form elements are First & Last name & Email address. Once they signup, a confirmation email is sent.

Now, I would like to include a link within the email to verify the email address they have provided and then create the contact. Is it something possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for technical validation try this:

1. Create a webform field type Email
2. Install [Webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module (if you don't already have it) and implement rule "Equal Values".
3. Apply validation rule to emails for webform and CiviCRM by using the checkbox.

Comment: Great Find!! Although Its not exactly what I was looking for but it does the job. Thank you!!! Also I have found email verify module, which allows to check existence of email host before submission. combination of both would eliminate the typos.

Comment: On another note, I was not been able to include the First name in the automated email. I have tried like [submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name:nolabel] , but no luck. Any tips please?

Comment: Ah yes Email Verify module -> create an answer yourself and stick that in there so it does not get burried in the comments

Comment: On tokens -> best to ask a seperate SE Q for that - get more people's eyes on it; we rarely send Emails not CiviCRM

Answer (score 3):

Along with [Webform validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation), [email verify module](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_verify) can be used, which allows to check existence of email host before submission. combination of both should eliminate the typos.